# How to access the main Google homepage (no country redirect)

Tags: google-search

Normally when you go to google.com it redirects you to the homepage for your country (e.g. if it detects that you're in India, it redirects you to google.co.in). What link can I go to if I want it to always take me to the generic Google homepage?

Answer (score 5):

http://www.google.com/ncr

Answer (score 4):

http://www.google.com/ncr should do it.